# Jquery Path animation issue

Tags: jquery

I am trying to rotate a **P tag** along the circumference of a circle using jquery path
https://github.com/weepy/jquery.path

Below is my code

**Html**

```
<p class='demo'>Hi</p>
```

**Css**

```
.demo
{
 -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
-moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
-ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
-o-transition: all 500ms ease;
transition: all 500ms ease;
background: #3fbf79;
width:50px;
}
```

**Javascript with the jquery path Plugin**

```
 $(window).load(function(){
        $('.demo').click(function(){
var arc_params = {
    center: [285,185],  
        radius: 100,    
        start: 30,
        end: 200,
        dir: -1
  }
$(this).animate({path : new $.path.arc(arc_params)},1000)


});
        });
```

**-------------------------------------**

```
/*
 * jQuery css bezier animation support -- Jonah Fox
 * version 0.0.1
 * Released under the MIT license.
 */
/*
  var path = $.path.bezier({
    start: {x:10, y:10, angle: 20, length: 0.3},
    end:   {x:20, y:30, angle: -20, length: 0.2}
  })
  $("myobj").animate({path: path}, duration)

*/

;(function($){

  $.path = {};

  var V = {
    rotate: fu

nction(p, degrees) {
          var radians = degrees * Math.PI / 180,
            c = Math.cos(radians),
            s = Math.sin(radians);
          return [c*p[0] - s*p[1], s*p[0] + c*p[1]];
        },
        scale: function(p, n) {
          return [n*p[0], n*p[1]];
        },
        add: function(a, b) {
          return [a[0]+b[0], a[1]+b[1]];
        },
        minus: function(a, b) {
          return [a[0]-b[0], a[1]-b[1]];
        }
      };

      $.path.bezier = function( params, rotate ) {
        params.start = $.extend( {angle: 0, length: 0.3333}, params.start );
        params.end = $.extend( {angle: 0, length: 0.3333}, params.end );

        this.p1 = [params.start.x, params.start.y];
        this.p4 = [params.end.x, params.end.y];

        var v14 = V.minus( this.p4, this.p1 ),
          v12 = V.scale( v14, params.start.length ),
          v41 = V.scale( v14, -1 ),
          v43 = V.scale( v41, params.end.length );

        v12 = V.rotate( v12, params.start.angle );
        this.p2 = V.add( this.p1, v12 );

        v43 = V.rotate(v43, params.end.angle );
        this.p3 = V.add( this.p4, v43 );

        this.f1 = function(t) { return (t*t*t); };
        this.f2 = function(t) { return (3*t*t*(1-t)); };
        this.f3 = function(t) { return (3*t*(1-t)*(1-t)); };
        this.f4 = function(t) { return ((1-t)*(1-t)*(1-t)); };

        /* p from 0 to 1 */
        this.css = function(p) {
          var f1 = this.f1(p), f2 = this.f2(p), f3 = this.f3(p), f4=this.f4(p), css = {};
          if (rotate) {
            css.prevX = this.x;
            css.prevY = this.y;
          }
          css.x = this.x = ( this.p1[0]*f1 + this.p2[0]*f2 +this.p3[0]*f3 + this.p4[0]*f4 +.5 )|0;
          css.y = this.y = ( this.p1[1]*f1 + this.p2[1]*f2 +this.p3[1]*f3 + this.p4[1]*f4 +.5 )|0;
          css.left = css.x + "px";
          css.top = css.y + "px";
          return css;
        };
      };

      $.path.arc = function(params, rotate) {
        for ( var i in params ) {
          this[i] = params[i];
        }

        this.dir = this.dir || 1;

        while ( this.start > this.end && this.dir > 0 ) {
          this.start -= 360;
        }

        while ( this.start < this.end && this.dir < 0 ) {
          this.start += 360;
        }

        this.css = function(p) {
          var a = ( this.start * (p ) + this.end * (1-(p )) ) * Math.PI / 180,
            css = {};

          if (rotate) {
            css.prevX = this.x;
            css.prevY = this.y;
          }
          css.x = this.x = ( Math.sin(a) * this.radius + this.center[0] +.5 )|0;
          css.y = this.y = ( Math.cos(a) * this.radius + this.center[1] +.5 )|0;
          css.left = css.x + "px";
          css.top = css.y + "px";
          return css;
        };
      };

      $.fx.step.path = function(fx) {
        var css = fx.end.css( 1 - fx.pos );
        if ( css.prevX != null ) {
          $.cssHooks.transform.set( fx.elem, "rotate(" + Math.atan2(css.prevY - css.y, css.prevX - css.x) + ")" );
        }
        fx.elem.style.top = css.top;
        fx.elem.style.left = css.left;
      };

    })(jQuery);
```

**Link TO JS FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=txCJNRs8ty

**Issue**

**Animation does not function.**

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element you are trying to move must be `position:absolute` :)

Comment: In OP's context this may be right. But we can animate elements with some other positioning too.